# Javascript - subscribe to an event of a page from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, popup

I want to be able to open a popup using window.open and subscribe to page events (onload etc) of the popup in the opener. So i'd want a method in my opener (parent page) to execute when the popup's onload or ready fires. Is this possible using plain js or jquery? Pls don't ask me why i want to do this - this can solve a lot of issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

First page (x.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var w = window.open('y.html', 'w');
    w.document.getElementById('target').onclick = function () { alert('!'); };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second page (y.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="target">target</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Works for me...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/body there is no onclick for the body in gecko; but the example is still valid. try this --> http://jsbin.com/acefew/2/edit#javascript

Comment: @shawndumas this doesn't work if the popup is another page (in the same domain of course). I want this to work with two different pages.

Comment: I added html to the answer. Make two html files with the content and try it. It works for me...

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry for not being very clear. OnClick works but iam not able to subscribe to OnLoad nor to jquery Ready events. @shawndumas, any way i can make this work?